# save ImageField mongoengine

Tags: python, tornado, mongoengine

I have following class definition in mongoengine orm:

```
import mongoengine as me

class Description(me.Document):
    user = me.ReferenceField(User, required=True)
    name = me.StringField(required=True, max_length=50)
    caption = me.StringField(required=True, max_length=80)
    description = me.StringField(required=True, max_length=100)
    image = me.ImageField()
```

in my post method of my tornado web requesthandler:

```
from PIL import Image

def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    merchant = self._merchant
    data = self._data
    obj_data = {}
    if merchant:
        params = self.serialize() # I am getting params dict. NO Issues with this.
        obj_data['name'] = params.get('title', None)
        obj_data['description'] = params.get('description', None)
        path = params.get('file_path', None)
        image = Image.open(path)
        print image # **
        obj_data['image'] = image # this is also working fine.
        obj_data['caption'] = params.get('caption', None)
        obj_data['user'] = user
        des = Description(**obj_data)
        des.save()

        print obj_data['image'] # **
        print des.image # This is printing as <ImageGridFsProxy: None>
```

**   print obj_data['image']  and print image are printing following:

```
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=1 size=290x290 at 0x7F83AE0E91B8>
```

but

> des.image still remains None.

Please suggest me what is wrong here.

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: What about other attributes of `promo`? Are they ok?

Comment: Hi alexvassel,

I have edited it again. Some correction. promo is actually description.
apologies. Rest is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not just put PIL objects into a field with `obj.image = image` that way. You must do:

```
des = Description()
des.image.put(open(params.get('file_path', None)))
des.save()
```

In other words, `ImageField` should be filled with file object after creating an instance by calling `put` method.